# Designing a N-tier Java EE web application having views, webservice and scheduler with spring

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, architecture, n-tier-architecture

I have a start up web application using Spring and Hibernate which currently has 3 layers. View, Service and DAO. It also the domain objects are segregated separately.

[image: Existing package structure]

To this I want to add **webservice and scheduler** . Now which layers  should I add these classes? Or shall I create new packages for these? What are the best practices on n-tier web applications?

Please share your thoughts and experiences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few thoughts:

1. A package is not a tier.  A tier (or layer) is a logical abstraction for a collection of related functionality, a package is a physical grouping tool for compilation units.  It may be the case that all the classes used to implement a logical tier reside in the same source package, but there is no requirement that this is the case.
2. It seems like `webservice` would fit nicely in the `service` package, or maybe a subpackge within `service` called `web`.
3. For the scheduler, it may also belong somewhere in the `service` package (particularly if other components are meant to interface with the scheduler via a service API).  If not, then the next most appropriate thing would be to give it its own package called `scheduler`.

As for best practices, just do what 1) works and 2) makes sense.  "n-tier web applications" is a topic so broad that there aren't really any specific answers that apply in all possible cases.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If add a webservice(which will be consuming other services) to the service package, Will it not be against the clean separation of layers?

Comment: Not really, separation of layers has much more to do with how the code is coupled together internally than with what package the source files happen to reside in.  For instance, if your code is only loosely coupled (or not coupled at all) to other service implementations then you have maintained clean separation of layers.  However, if it is tightly coupled/dependent upon the implementation of another service in order to function then you don't have a clean separation of layers, and simply relocating the code to a different package *will not* change that.

Answer (score 3):

To web and scheduler packages?

There's no "right" answer to this question, and without any idea regarding your package layout beyond what's shown, it's difficult to be more specific.

As long as it makes sense in context, and it's consistent, it really doesn't matter a whole lot anyway. And you may find that your existing structure changes after you identify and refactor functionality across the original and new functionality.